# Twitter app on iOS 9 doesn't connect through proxy

Tags: proxy, twitter

I'm connecting to a local proxy to access internet on my iPhone/iOS 9 but Twitter app seems not using the global proxy i've set for my wifi...

Other apps like Chrome & Safari are working just fine!

Comment: are any other apps not going through the proxy you set ? normally any iOS that uses NSURLConnection to make internet requests go through the settings you set in Settings -> Wifi. Maybe twitter is using cellular data instead of wifi.

Comment: I've set proxy in Settings > Wifi and as far as I've tested all apps are using it well just Twitter... I turned off cellular data, nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

iOS 9 implements App Transport Security on each individual application. This is a setting that is enabled by default on all iOS 9 apps. Application developers that wish to allow their apps to be proxied can disable this setting in the applications plist file. If you are on a jailbroken device you can also manually modify this file.

Alternatively I found this that should work, haven't tried yet though
https://nabla-c0d3.github.io/blog/2015/12/01/burp-ios9-ats/

Comment: Thank you for the contribution to this question's resolution. However, please add quotes from external link, as the answer would have lost or reduced value if the link died